# Regex for catching this part

Tags: c#, regex

I just wanna grab with a regex the name from this text:

```
 Name: 
 Paul Rao  

 Company: 
 Fix UR Gadget
```

I should get only **Paul Rao**

I tried `(?<=Name:)[\s\S]*\n` but it's not working, any ideas ?

The part Name: (newline, space ...) actual name (space ...newline) will be the same, but Company will not be always the text under.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Why do you need to use regular expressions?  Can you not use any other technique?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can avoid using lookbehind if you use a group capture:

```
var result = Regex.Match(text, @"Name:[\r\n ]+([^\r\n]*)[\r\n ]+")
```

Your result would be `result.Groups[1].Value.TrimEnd()`

Comment: working with this one, thanks a lot :) how do I select good answer ?

Answer (score 0):

```
(?<=Name:[\s\S\n]*)[a-zA-Z\s\-]*
```

---

`(?<=Name:[\s\S]*)` Makes sure there is the word "Name", a semicolon, and any number of whitespace characters before the match. (You may want to even switch `*` with `+`, since you can guarantee the whitespace, but this will work)

`[a-zA-Z\s\-]*` Matches any number of letters, spaces, or hyphens (Since a hyphen is a valid character for a name). Ever heard the story of La-a (Luh-dash-uh)? There may even be other valid characters, I dunno.

Comment: works fine for me.. :) Are you making sure to do something like string regex = **@**"(?<=Name:[\s\S]*)[a-zA-Z\s\-]*"; (Using the `@` to prevent escaping)

Comment: I am actually using Zennoposter, which is made in .NET, and uses the .NET regex, the regex that you posted, works fine, the first match, is the name, but I see that my processor is blowing while processing.

Answer (score 0):

Any ideas? No, because its a question about regexes; yes, because parsing can actually be fun without the crime against humanity which are regexes.

Take a look at the tutorials on this website, for instance (not sure if this is your best option; havnt done parsing on .NET myself, but it looks excellent on the surface)

http://www.quanttec.com/fparsec/

If you are willing to make a small time investment of an hour or so, I promise you wont look back.

Comment: This isn't an answer and the question clearly states C#, not F#.

Comment: I dont know if you ever worked with .NET languages, but interop between managed languages is 100% effortless. I bet there is a one-line example on that website that he could copy into an F# module, and it would work right off the bat; even without necessarily understanding much F#. Whether Andrei consideres that an answer; I am going to leave that to him. Lets hope he finds it more helpful than your remark.

Answer (score 0):

How about this one: `^Name:[^\S\n]$\n(.*)\n`

Comment: still getting too many matches... but as I said, company won't be always there.

Answer (score 0):

Nice a try with your lookbehind. You just forgot there's a new line there.

```
(?<=Name:\n)([^\n]*+)
```

Now the second group should match it.

Answer (score 0):

```
string text = @"
Name: 
Paul Rao  

Company: 
Fix UR Gadget 
";
Regex re = new Regex(@"Name:\s*\n(.+?)\s*\n");
Match m = re.Match(text);
if (m.Success)
{
    string name = m.Groups[1].Value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        var match = Regex.Match(text, @"Name:[\s]*(.+)(?:$|\r)");
        var name = match.Groups[1].Value;
```